# Add menu item programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-menu

Hi I would like to add item menu programmatically. I know how to add menu item in XML but how can i achieve this dynamically? I didn't find anything about this in internet... Is it possible at all? I would like to achieve something like this: https://youtu.be/Es5UFII4oak?t=832 (but in JAVA)

Comment: Hi. You mention java and link a video about an android application...
You should first explain what's your environment, your need and what you've tried.
And have a look on how to ask a question on SO or your question may be closed.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` when you want to add the item.

After you click the add button, you should invoke the `InvalidateOptionsMenu();` Here is code.

```
   [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        EditText menu_item;
        EditText menu_name;
        List<string> list;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
             menu_item = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.menu_item);
             menu_name = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.menu_name);
            Button add = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            list= new List<string>();
            add.Click += Add_Click;
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
       //  int item_id=   Integer.ParseInt(menu_item.Text.ToString());
            string menu_name_text = menu_name.Text.ToString();
            list.Add(menu_name_text);

            ApplyChanged();
        }

        public void ApplyChanged()
        {
            InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            menu.Clear();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                menu.Add(item);
            }

            return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Here is layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="id"
    android:id="@+id/menu_item"/>

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="name"
    android:id="@+id/menu_name"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is running Gif.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but how can i identify particular menu item  and add some function to it?

Comment: You can override `public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)`, to handle the click item event, add some function to it, but you should judege the users' input name of menu item. If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer(Click ✔ in the upper right corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.